# subscribing to a tag with python-instagram API in python failing

Tags: python, instagram

I'm trying to subscribe to a hashtag using the python-instagram wrapper for python. I have previously used cURL to perform the authentication handshake and it worked fine. However, I would like to use all the wrapper functionality.

```
from instagram import client, subscriptions
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect, abort, flash,     jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

api = client.InstagramAPI(client_id="", client_secret="")

callback_url = 'http://localhost.com:515'
api.create_subscription(object='tag',object_id='bacon', aspect='media', callback_url=callback_url)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def handshake():
code = request.args.get('hub.challenge')
if code:
    return code 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
app.run(host='localhost.com',port=515)
```

The error I get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    api.create_subscription(object='tag',object_id='bacon', aspect='media', callback_url=callback_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 152, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 144, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 100, in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.')
instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

When I remove the create_subscription line it seems to be fine, but the create_subscription method does something strange and I can't figure out what. The end goal is to subscribe to the tag and receive new pictures posted with the tag.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to various issues:

1. Make sure your callback_url is up and available for remote hosts
2. Debug your handshake() and make sure you return the value (put prints)
3. Debug your /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/instagram/bind.py and see the response with error message, this can be the answer))
4. Make your handshake() to accept POST from instagram
5. probably you should use authenticated api in this case

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is wrong. You need to create an instance of InstagramAPI like this:

```
client = InstagramAPI(access_token=my_access_token,
                      client_id=my_client_id,
                      client_secret=my_client_secret)
```

If what you need is to authenticate you have to do it like this:

```
client = InstagramAPI(client_id=my_client_id,
                      client_secret=my_client_secret,
                      redirect_uri="http://localhost")
authurl = client.get_authorize_login_url(scope=["basic", "relationships", "likes", "public_content"]) # or whatever scopes you need
```